# Call procedure or function as part of Hibernate query

Tags: sql, nhibernate

I need to return records filtered and sorted by complex logic.
I am planing to make sorting and filtering at the database side (function or stored procedure).

Is it possible to call procedure or function at the QueryOver or Criteria syntax in order to make filtering of the query?

Something like code shown below, where CallProcedure - calling my procedure/function

```
var articles = Session.QueryOver<ArticleData>()
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == 1)
    .CallProcedure???
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(number).List();
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would need to register your function with NHibernate, by creating a custom dialect:

```
public class MyDialect : MsSqlServer2008Dialect
{
    public MyDialect() 
    {
        RegisterFunction("myfunction", new SQLFunctionTemplate(...));
    }
}
```

After that, you can use the function within your query:

```
var articles = Session.QueryOver<ArticleData>()
    .Where(x => x.CompanyId == 1)
    .Where(Projections.SqlFunction("myfunction", ...))
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(number).List();
```

Something along those lines. Not sure if you'll be able to do both filter and sort with it though. Maybe a [database view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963020/strategies-for-mapping-views-in-nhibernate) will be more appropriate for that case.

Some links to get you started:
[Can I use SQL functions in NHibernate QueryOver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966986/nhibernate-queryover-use-sql-functions)
[NHibernate QueryOver SQLFunction in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097193/nhibernate-queryover-sqlfunction-in-where-clause)
[Can NHibernate's QueryOver syntax select MAX() of an SqlFunction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867395/can-nhibernates-queryover-syntax-select-max-of-an-sqlfunction)